# Is there an easy way to tell if my (EBS) volume is encrypted without using the awscli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I would like to see if my EBS volume is encrypted without having to use the AWS CLI (or require the AWS credentials)

Is there a way by which I can tell if a volume is encrypted?  Perhaps via some heuristics?

Comment: Any particular motivation?  An unused volume should appear to be be filled with garbage as the `0x00` on the new disk is "decrypted" I suspect but it seems unlikely that there's a good way since the instance kernel is apparently unaware of the encryption.